# Random time delay

Tags: c++, operating-system, signals

I'm trying to send signals between processes and I need to allow a random time delay of between 0.01 and 0.1 seconds in my signal generation loop. So this is what I'm doing and it is most certainly not between 0.01 and 0.1, but comes out as 1 second. Not sure what I'm missing here.

```
    sleepTime = 100000L+(long)((1e6-1e5)*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));        
    usleep(sleepTime);
```

Answer (score 30):

If you've got C++11:

```
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937_64 eng{std::random_device{}()};  // or seed however you want
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{10, 100};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{dist(eng)});
}
```

It may not be what your prof is looking for. :-)

Comment: I've never seen empty <> in C++ ... can you explain what they are for?

Comment: @FelixDombek: for instantiating a template that provides default arguments. Also used when you fully specialize a template.

Comment: -1, and now for the understatement of the year: unnecessarily complex.

Comment: -1: this is the most hilariously verbose stl monstrosity I've seen in a while

Comment: +1, I think this is great because it re-uses the math that someone else wrote.

Comment: Maybe this was too complex in 2011 but now that c++11 is available in any new compiler, this would be the preferred way to do it. In any case, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All of your constants are 10x too large! Try

```
 sleepTime = 10000L+(long)((1e5-1e4)*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1) `100000L` is 100 msec, not 10 msec

2) usleep is only guaranteed to sleep for at least the argument time, with no guarantee about how long it will sleep.  Read the manpage: all sleep functions make that assertion.

3) How are you measuring how long it takes?  Are you using a timer that has milli or microsecond resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to generate a random number between 0 and 1, then use a `lerp` function to move the number to being between 0.01 and 0.1.

```
// returns random between 0 and 1
float randFloat() ;

// you are "val" % of the way from min to max
float lerp( float val, float min, float max ) ;
```